# select query on postgis not working for specific fields

Tags: postgresql, select, postgis

So I have what seems to be a really weird problem.

I have imported a table from QGIS into a postgresql + postgis database. 
I simply want to select a few columns from that, but I can't. [image]

whats funny is that i can use the select query for the lowercase fields and it works, but not for the uppercase ones, such as LABELRANK. the error shows that such a column does not exist.

why is that so?

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. We appreciate your participation. However, the community does expect a certain quality in the questions posted. Consider reading the article: [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Currently your questiond doesn't contain enough information and might be closed as [***unclear what you're asking***](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). For example; Why don't you just show us your simple `SELECT` statement in your question, so that we can determine that you don't have a "simple" syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this columns names has been created using double-quotes.

You should use double-quotes in your SELECT statement.

> ```
> create table tbl (field1 int, "FIELD2" int, field3 int);
> ```

> ```
> insert into tbl values (1,2,3),(4,5,6);
> ```

> ```
> select field1, field2, field3 from tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  column "field2" does not exist
> LINE 1: select field1, field2, field3 from tbl;
>                        ^
> HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "tbl.field1" or the column "tbl.field3".
> ```

> ```
> select field1, "FIELD2", field3 from tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> field1 | FIELD2 | field3
> -----: | -----: | -----:
>      1 |      2 |      3
>      4 |      5 |      6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=6103a83e7fb41d88157e6ddc1ac68db9)*

Comment: yes thank you. I didn't realize that sql doesn't recognize capital letters like this